# How to set parameters for DeepFlow optical flow algorithm

Tags: opencv, opencv3.1

The [documentation of `cv::optflow::createOptFlow_DeepFlow`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d84/group__optflow.html#ga5e735547610172695cb0b39495af9d6d) states:

```
Parameters - class fields - that may be modified after creating a class instance
```

How can one modify these parameters? All one gets is a `Ptr<DenseOpticalFlow>` and [`cv::optflow::OpticalFlowDeepFlow`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/4ed940cc9f0ab586804fe0a90a5d9898402be5cf/modules/optflow/src/deepflow.cpp#L51) is not in the public interface, so one can not even `dynamic_cast` to it.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't based on https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/optflow/src/deepflow.cpp.

Comment: I was able to set the parameters by creating a dummy `DenseOpticalFlow` subclass with the same layout and `reinterpret_cast`ing the algorithm to that class. It's UB, though.